# Camel - How to move files based on existence on other file in same folder

Tags: apache-camel

Let's say in Temp folder i have (one,two,three,four,five)5 files and i want to these files to Test folder.

My question is here I want to move 'one.txt' file if 'three.txt' file exists then both one,two files has to move temp folder. same-way ('two.txt' file if 'five.txt').

I am very new to apache - camel and my route looks like below

```
<route id="Helloworld">
<camel:from uri="file:C:\\Temp?noop=true"></camel:from>
<camel:choice>
    <camel:when>
        <camel:simple>${file:onlyname.noext} regex 'one'</camel:simple>
        <camel:choice>
            <camel:when>
                <method ref="myBean" method="predicateThatChecksIfFileExists(${file:parent}\\three.xml)" />
                -- Here i want to move one and three both the files has to move Test folder
            </camel:when>
        </camel:choice>
    </camel:when>
</camel:choice>
```

What is happening here, each file taking from folder and processing it and but we can't check about other file in same folder. Could anyone please suggest me, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: From your predicate just set a variable in camel header. And in your route just check for this variable and only if its present the go ahead with the transfer

Comment: Isn't this easier to do with java 8 streams? Create a processor to this for you. Remember Camel is based on EIP with I being integration. This is not integration. Don't try to fit every possible scenario in the Camel world.

Comment: Exactly, dont have this weird rules - is there even a valid business requirement behind this. You can write 10 lines of Java code and use the Java File API to move files. You can use a timer to trigger your Java code if you want to run it periodically.